# How to show image in header of datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

How to show image in header of datagrid in WPF ? We need to show both image and text.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can simply create a HeaderTemplate for your gridcolumn

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyHeaderTemplate">
 <Grid><!-- i'm too lazy to layout all here :) -->
   <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MyComponent;Component/Images/MyImg.png"/>
   <Textblock Text="MyHeaderText"/>
 </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

if you use it this way you workaround the column visibility bug of the datagrid with Image headers (if you toogle visibility for an image header column you get an error otherwise).

Comment: you just have to put this declaration into a Resources area from Usercontrol or window or datagrid. what error you got?